# Springboot war deployment to tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I have built a spring boot war file using maven, When I try to deploy the war file to an external tomcat server in command prompt. I get an exception.

**Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver**

I am using two application.properties files one in src/main/resources that has the actual datasource config to Oracle and another in src/test/resources that has a datasource for a H2 in memory database.

Please let me know if I missed anything, Like placing the property file in config under tomcat folder etc.

Comment: This given exception is throwing while you running your application or test cases?

Comment: While running the app with springboot embedded server from eclipse it runs without any errors. Only when deploying the war to Tomcat the errors occur (by placing the war file in webapps in Tomcat).

Comment: Verify the runtime dependencies for datasource like Oracle.  Check if you oracle jar is not included to tomcat's lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have set oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver as driver-class-name on your application.properties under src/main/java, right? Did you remember to include this dependency on pom.xml similar to what follows?

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
      <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit**

Try adding this to tomcat's context.xml:

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="xxx" password="xxx" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
           url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
```

Comment: I'ev tried that, it dint work. I think it's not able to look for the auto-config DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class

Answer (score 0):

Okay, The root cause of this is there is no oracle6 jar in my war file - Even though I added the dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Therefore I've added the jar explicitly into my Tomcat lib and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I added the Datasource Configuration using the programmatic way as below and it worked, not sure why couldn't it be picked from application.properties.

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {
@Bean
public DataSource datasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
      .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
      .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db")
      .username("username")
      .password("password")
      .build(); 
   }
}
```

Credits to Baeldung article [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source)

Comment: the issue here is that the configuration is read but the dependency is not resolved. You may want to reconsider your response